# IPx8 rating test

Tags: mechanical-engineering, waterproofing

Do I need to perform all the lower IPx(1-7) rating tests to achieve an IPx8 rating or covers the IPx8 rating test all the other ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following comes from the [Siemens summary of the IEC 60529 IP rating](https://assets.new.siemens.com/siemens/assets/api/uuid:7f2844f1-502a-4c23-b123-117894c39a8c/ip-vs-nema-whitepaper-icp-us.pdf):

> Note on the second characteristic numeral (protection
> against ingress of water):
> Up to and including characteristic numeral 6, the
> requirements of all lower characteristic numerals are also
> met. The same is not true for characteristic numerals 7, 8
> and 9.
> If an enclosure meets several requirements, this must also
> be indicated as appropriate.

So it looks like the answer is not quite. In particular, IPx6 (strong water jet) and IPx7/8 (water immersion) might be independent of each other.